# Problema con Hibernate y Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Tengo un error al momento de iniciar mi aplicación creada con Spring Boot v2.5.6. Tengo la siguiente tabla en una base de datos ya existente en Oracle 11g.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy desarrollando una API con arquitectura REST con Spring Web, Oracle Driver, Spring Data JPA y Lombok. He creado el siguiente modelo

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "USUARIO")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Usuario {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_USU")
    private Long idUsu;
    @Column(name = "ID_PERFIL")
    private Long idPerfil;
    @Column(name = "USERNAME", length = 15)
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "PASSWORD", length = 250)
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "RUN_USU")
    private Long rut;
    @Column(name = "NOMBRE_USU", length = 60)
    private String nombre;
    @Column(name = "AP_PATERNO_USU", length = 60)
    private String aPaterno;
    @Column(name = "AP_MATERNO_USU", length = 60)
    private String aMaterno;
    @Column(name = "FONO_USU", length = 15)
    private String telefono;
    @Column(name = "MAIL_USU", length = 60)
    private String correo;
    @Column(name = "APP_USU", length = 2)
    private char app;
    @Column(name = "ACTIVO_USU", length = 1)
    private char activo;
    @Column(name = "INI_USU", length = 1)
    private char ini;
    @Column(name = "ID_SIGE")
    private Long idSige;
    @Column(name = "HASH_REC", length = 20)
    private String hash;
    @Column(name = "R_CERTIFICADO", length = 500)
    private String certificado;

}
```

Luego he creado el siguiente repositorio y los respectivos servicios con su interfaz.

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface UsuarioRepo extends JpaRepository<Usuario, Long> {
    Usuario encontrarPorNombreDeUsuario(String username);
}
```

```
import java.util.List;

public interface UsuarioServicio {
    Usuario insertarUsuario(Usuario u);

    Usuario getUser(String username);

    List<Usuario> obtenerTodosLosUsuarios();
}
```

```
package cl.gob.interior.sirc.servicio;

import cl.gob.interior.sirc.dominio.Usuario;
import cl.gob.interior.sirc.repositorio.UsuarioRepo;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Transactional
@Slf4j
public class UsuarioServicioImplementacion implements UsuarioServicio {

    private final UsuarioRepo usuarioRepo;

    @Override
    public Usuario insertarUsuario(Usuario u) {
        log.info("Se ha guardado el usuario {} en la base de datos", u.getUsername());
        return usuarioRepo.save(u);
    }

    @Override
    public Usuario getUser(String username) {
        log.info("Se esta buscando el usuario con nombre de usuario = {}", username);
        return usuarioRepo.encontrarPorNombreDeUsuario(username);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Usuario> obtenerTodosLosUsuarios() {
        log.info("Se estan buscando todos los usuarios");
        return usuarioRepo.findAll();
    }
}
```

Para ultimo implementar un ControladorRest

```
package cl.gob.interior.sirc.api;

import cl.gob.interior.sirc.dominio.Usuario;
import cl.gob.interior.sirc.servicio.UsuarioServicio;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/Usuario")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UsuarioRecurso {
    private final UsuarioServicio usuarioServicio;

    @GetMapping("/Login")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Usuario>> getUsuarios() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(usuarioServicio.obtenerTodosLosUsuarios());
    }
}
```

Hasta aquí todo debería funcionar bien, el problema que cuando arranco la aplicación en modo spring boot me arroja el siguiente error en la ejecución del programa:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'usuarioRecurso' defined in file [C:\Users\Juan Fernando\Desktop\proyectos\sirc\target\classes\cl\gob\interior\sirc\api\UsuarioRecurso.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'usuarioServicioImplementacion' defined in file [C:\Users\Juan Fernando\Desktop\proyectos\sirc\target\classes\cl\gob\interior\sirc\servicio\UsuarioServicioImplementacion.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'usuarioRepo' defined in cl.gob.interior.sirc.repositorio.UsuarioRepo defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract cl.gob.interior.sirc.dominio.Usuario cl.gob.interior.sirc.repositorio.UsuarioRepo.encontrarPorNombreDeUsuario(java.lang.String)! Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract cl.gob.interior.sirc.dominio.Usuario cl.gob.interior.sirc.repositorio.UsuarioRepo.encontrarPorNombreDeUsuario(java.lang.String)! No property encontrarPorNombreDeUsuario found for type Usuario!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract cl.gob.interior.sirc.dominio.Usuario cl.gob.interior.sirc.repositorio.UsuarioRepo.encontrarPorNombreDeUsuario(java.lang.String)! No property encontrarPorNombreDeUsuario found for type Usuario!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) [spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) [spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) [spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) [spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) [spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at cl.gob.interior.sirc.SircApplication.main(SircApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'usuarioServicioImplementacion' defined in file [C:\Users\Juan Fernando\Desktop\proyectos\sirc\target\classes\cl\gob\interior\sirc\servicio\UsuarioServicioImplementacion.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'usuarioRepo' defined in cl.gob.interior.sirc.repositorio.UsuarioRepo defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract cl.gob.interior.sirc.dominio.Usuario cl.gob.interior.sirc.repositorio.UsuarioRepo.encontrarPorNombreDeUsuario(java.lang.String)! Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract cl.gob.interior.sirc.dominio.Usuario cl.gob.interior.sirc.repositorio.UsuarioRepo.encontrarPorNombreDeUsuario(java.lang.String)! No property encontrarPorNombreDeUsuario found for type Usuario!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract cl.gob.interior.sirc.dominio.Usuario cl.gob.interior.sirc.repositorio.UsuarioRepo.encontrarPorNombreDeUsuario(java.lang.String)! No property encontrarPorNombreDeUsuario found for type Usuario!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'usuarioRepo' defined in cl.gob.interior.sirc.repositorio.UsuarioRepo defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract cl.gob.interior.sirc.dominio.Usuario cl.gob.interior.sirc.repositorio.UsuarioRepo.encontrarPorNombreDeUsuario(java.lang.String)! Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract cl.gob.interior.sirc.dominio.Usuario cl.gob.interior.sirc.repositorio.UsuarioRepo.encontrarPorNombreDeUsuario(java.lang.String)! No property encontrarPorNombreDeUsuario found for type Usuario!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract cl.gob.interior.sirc.dominio.Usuario cl.gob.interior.sirc.repositorio.UsuarioRepo.encontrarPorNombreDeUsuario(java.lang.String)! No property encontrarPorNombreDeUsuario found for type Usuario!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract cl.gob.interior.sirc.dominio.Usuario cl.gob.interior.sirc.repositorio.UsuarioRepo.encontrarPorNombreDeUsuario(java.lang.String)! Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract cl.gob.interior.sirc.dominio.Usuario cl.gob.interior.sirc.repositorio.UsuarioRepo.encontrarPorNombreDeUsuario(java.lang.String)! No property encontrarPorNombreDeUsuario found for type Usuario!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract cl.gob.interior.sirc.dominio.Usuario cl.gob.interior.sirc.repositorio.UsuarioRepo.encontrarPorNombreDeUsuario(java.lang.String)! No property encontrarPorNombreDeUsuario found for type Usuario!
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException.create(QueryCreationException.java:101) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:106) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1051) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:86) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:86) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:360) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:323) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:230) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:329) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    ... 49 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract cl.gob.interior.sirc.dominio.Usuario cl.gob.interior.sirc.repositorio.UsuarioRepo.encontrarPorNombreDeUsuario(java.lang.String)! No property encontrarPorNombreDeUsuario found for type Usuario!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:96) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:113) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:254) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:87) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:102) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    ... 71 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property encontrarPorNombreDeUsuario found for type Usuario!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:90) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:437) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:413) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:366) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:324) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:348) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:331) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:249) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:250) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:383) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:384) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:92) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:89) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    ... 75 common frames omitted

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:54545', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Siento decirte que Spring no habla español: si el método del repository se llamara findByUsername seguramente te funcionará

Comment: Sí, investigando logré dar con la solución. En el repositorio para buscar una entidad por alguna propiedad tiene que ser igual a la propiedad de la clase. Por ejemplo, username, en el repo debe ser findByUsername(); Obviamente, con los métodos en ingles.

Answer (score 3):

Un par de observaciones:

1. encontrarPorNombreDeUsuario en el repositorio no debería estar en inglés? **findByName**
2. En usuarioServicioImplementacion, declaras esto:
   private final UsuarioRepo usuarioRepo;

no deberías agregarlo al constructor, dado que estás haciendo una inyeccion de dependencia por constructor, lo mimso aplica para tu controlador. De la siguiente manera

private final UsuarioServicio usuarioServicio;

```
public UsuarioRecurso (UsuarioServicio usuarioServicio) {
    this.usuarioServicio= usuarioServicio;
}
```

Este ejemplo en el controlador, hacer lo mismo para el repositorio.

3. No creaste tu sequenceGenerator en tu entidad y tampoco tu generatedValue en el id de tu entidad.

Finalmente, asegurate de tener las dependencias correctas en tu pom.xml